# For which values of $k$ there exist an $r$ such that $\binom{d}{r}^2\cdot d=\binom{d}{k-1}\binom{d}{k}$?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, symmetry

Let $k<d$ be positive integers. For which values of $1<k<d$ (if any), does there exist an integer $1<r<d$, such that $\binom{d}{r}^2\cdot d=\binom{d}{k-1}\binom{d}{k}$?

$r=d$, $k=1$ work. Trying to plug $k=r$ or $k=r+1$ does not provide any other solutions. I guess that there are no other solutions, but I don't know how to prove this.

---

The motivation for this question comes from counting degrees of freedom, in an attempt to [find a variational interpretation for an equation.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/414719/is-there-a-variational-interpretation-for-the-equation-operatornamediv-bigw)

Comment: $k=1$ does not satisfy your assumption $k>1$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I should have mentioned that this is at the "extreme point" of the allowed range of the parameters.

Comment: Since ${d \choose k-1} = {d \choose k}\frac{k}{d-k+1}$ the equation can be re-written as ${d \choose r}^2 d(d-k+1) = {d \choose k}^2 k$ and then you may want to add the "elementary-number-theory" tag to the question.